# how to display the hash value from my sample data

Tags: perl

I'm learning perl at the moment, i wanted to ask help to answer this exercise.
My objective is to display the hash value of PartID 1,2,3
the sample output is displaying lot, wafer, program, version, testnames, testnumbers, hilimit, lolimit and partid values only.

**sample data**

```
lot=lot123
wafer=1
program=prgtest
version=1
Testnames,T1,T2,T3
Testnumbers,1,2,3
Hilimit,5,6,7
Lolimit,1,2,3
PartID,,,,
1,3,0,5
2,4,3,2
3,5,6,3
```

**This is my code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $file = "";

GetOptions ("infile=s" => \$file ) or die("Error in command line arguments\n");
my $lotid = "";

open(DATA, $file) or die "Couldn't open file $file";

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
#print "$line";
              if ( $line =~ /^lot=/ ) {
                             #print "$line \n";
                             my ($dump, $lotid) = split /=/, $line;
                             print "$lotid\n";
              }

              elsif ($line =~ /^program=/ ) {
                            my ($dump, $progid) = split /=/, $line;
                            print "$progid \n";  
              }

              elsif ($line =~ /^wafer=/ ) {
                            my ($dump, $waferid) = split /=/, $line;
                            print "$waferid \n";  
              }

              elsif ($line =~ /^version=/ ) {
                            my ($dump, $verid) = split /=/, $line;
                            print "$verid \n";  
              }
              elsif ($line =~ /^testnames/i) {

                             my ($dump, @arr) = split /\,/, $line;

                             foreach my $e (@arr) {
                                           print $e, "\n";
                             }
              }
                elsif ($line =~ /^testnumbers/i) {

                             my ($dump, @arr1) = split /\,/, $line;

                             foreach my $e1 (@arr1) {
                                           print $e1, "\n";
                             }
              }
                elsif ($line =~ /^hilimit/i) {

                             my ($dump, @arr2) = split /\,/, $line;

                             foreach my $e2 (@arr2) {
                                           print $e2, "\n";
                             }
              }
                elsif ($line =~ /^lolimit/i) {

                             my ($dump, @arr3) = split /\,/, $line;

                             foreach my $e3 (@arr3) {
                                           print $e3, "\n";
                             }
              }

}
```

Kindly help add to my code to display Partid 1,2,3 hash.

Comment: I think you need to be a little clearer. The `PartID` line has three empty fields on it. How do you get "PartID 1,2,3" from this data? Is it the first field from the three lines following the `PartID` line?

Comment: in my sample data above i declare it already PartID,,,,
1,3,0,5
2,4,3,2
3,5,6,3 the first number of the hash (1,2,3)  needs to display as output

Comment: As I asked before, is it the first number from the next three lines? You need to describe exactly how you get from your input data to "PartID 1,2,3". The job of a programmer is to turn vague specifications into working code. Your first task is always to define the algorithm that you will follow.

Comment: yes you are correct the first number from the next three lines. Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've rewritten your code a little to use a few more modern Perl idioms (along with some comments to explain what I've done). The bit I've added is near the bottom.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
# Added 'warnings' which you should always use
use warnings;
# Use say() instead of print()
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;

my $file = "";

GetOptions ("infile=s" => \$file)
  or die ("Error in command line arguments\n");

# Use a lexical variable for a filehandle.
# Use the (safer) 3-argument version of open().
# Add $! to the error message.
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Couldn't open file $file: $!";

# Read each record into $_ - which makes the following code simpler
while (<$fh>) {
  # Match on $_
  if ( /^lot=/ ) {
    # Use "undef" instead of a $dump variable.
    # split() works on $_ by default.
    my (undef, $lotid) = split /=/;
    # Use say() instead of print() - less punctuation :-)
    say $lotid;
  }

  elsif ( /^program=/ ) {
    my (undef, $progid) = split /=/;
    say $progid;  
  }

  elsif ( /^wafer=/ ) {
    my (undef, $waferid) = split /=/;
    say $waferid;  
  }

  elsif ( /^version=/ ) {
    my (undef, $verid) = split /=/;
    say $verid;  
  }

  elsif ( /^testnames/i) {
    my (undef, @arr) = split /\,/;

    # Changed all of these similar pieces of code
    # to use the same variable names. As they are
    # defined in different code blocks, they are 
    # completely separate variables.
    foreach my $e (@arr) {
      say $e;
    }
  }

  elsif ( /^testnumbers/i) {
    my (undef, @arr) = split /\,/;

    foreach my $e (@arr) {
      say $e;
    }
  }

  elsif ( /^hilimit/i) {
    my (undef, @arr) = split /\,/;

    foreach my $e (@arr) {
      say $e;
    }
  }

  elsif ( /^lolimit/i) {
    my (undef, @arr) = split /\,/;

    foreach my $e (@arr) {
      say $e;
    }
  }

  # And here's the new bit.
  # If we're on the "partid" line, then read the next
  # three lines, split each one and print the first
  # element from the list returned by split().
  elsif ( /^partid/i) {
    say +(split /,/, <$fh>)[0] for 1 .. 3;
  }
}
```

**Update:** By the way, there are no hashes anywhere in this code :-)

**Update 2:** I've just realised that you only have three different ways to process the data. So you can simplify your code drastically by using slightly more complex regexes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;

my $file = "";

GetOptions ("infile=s" => \$file)
  or die ("Error in command line arguments\n");

open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Couldn't open file $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
  # Single value - just print it.
  if ( /^(?:lot|program|wafer|version)=/ ) {
    my (undef, $value) = split /=/;
    say $value;
  }

  # List of values - split and print.
  elsif ( /^(?:testnames|testnumbers|hilimit|lolimit)/i) {
    my (undef, @arr) = split /\,/;

    foreach my $e (@arr) {
      say $e;
    }
  }

  # Extract values from following lines.
  elsif ( /^partid/i) {
    say +(split /,/, <$fh>)[0] for 1 .. 3;
  }
}
```